# Stop losses not executing correctly in backtesting

Tags: pine-script

When backtesting this strategy - https://www.tradingview.com/script/KtD3lHuv-TP-SL-Test/
Take profits are executing right on the set percentage (give or take a very small amount of slippage)
Stop losses are executing intermittently, most of the time on the close of the bar where target percentage is meet, not on the actual percentage.
Can't figure out why take profits are executing on the nose but not stop losses. Ive tried strategy.close with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the answer, you first need to understand how Pinescript works.

Pinescript's scripts (strategies included of course) gets executed on specific occasions, most notably on bar close. That means that if you are checking inside your script if the `close` price is lower than a specific price, then it will return `true` or `false` only on bar close.

For example, this code will only get executed on bar close, regardless of the intra-bar prices:

```
stoplossPercent = input.float(title='Stop Loss (%)', defval=1, minval=0.01, step=0.5, group='Stop Loss') * 0.01

slLongClose = close < strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stoplossPercent)

strategy.close('Long', qty_percent=100, comment='SL Long', when=slLongClose)
```

In addition to pinescript, TradingView offers a [broker emulator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#broker-emulator) for backtesting pinescript strategies, and from there you get the results you see of the backtesting. You can't really access the broker emulator directly, but I believe that most (if not all) the `strategy.*()` functions are sending and receiving information to and from that emulator.

If we'll take previous example, the `strategy.close()` order written there is exactly equal to **:

```
if slLongClose
    strategy.close('Long', qty_percent=100, comment='SL Long')
```

Basically it's saying to the pinescript system: "when you run the script (usually on bar close) check for this condition. If it returns `true` send this `strategy.close()` order to the broker emulator and he'll close the position immediately".

As you can imagine, this will almost never result in an exact price, since it only check for the `close` price when bar is closed.

But pinescript has a way to send take profit and stop loss (and even trailing) orders to the broker emulator using [some parameters](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit) of the `strategy.exit()` function. Here are some examples:

> **limit (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Profit target (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a limit order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or better). Priority of the parameter 'limit' is higher than priority of the parameter 'profit' ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.

> **stop (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss' ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.

To use this, you can write something like ***:

```
strategy.exit('SL', stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stoplossPercent))
```

This code will say to the pinescript system: "each time you run the code, send an exit order to the broker emulator stating that he should exit the position only if the price (not the `close` price of the closed bar) is lower than `strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stoplossPercent)`, and keep this SL order until I say otherwise".

When his kind of order received by the broker emulator, he will continuously check the "realtime" price and will exit the position if minimum price is reached. You can see it is being used in the example you've attached:

```
strategy.exit('TP1', qty_percent=q1, profit=per(tp1))
strategy.exit('TP2', qty_percent=q2, profit=per(tp2))
strategy.exit('TP3', qty_percent=q3, profit=per(tp3))
strategy.exit('TP4', profit=per(tp4))
```

Keep in mind that there are some limitations to the broker emulator. For example, on backtesting, the broker emulator gets only 4 prices per bar - `open`, `high`, `low` and `close`, and it needs to decide when to exit the trade according to only those values. In order to do that, it makes some assumptions, which in some cases will not reflect the true result. For premium members there are some tools to overcome this, but that's another subject.

** Actually, since the `when` parameter has been depreciated, you should write it with an `if` statement in the first place, but that's out of scoop for now.

*** I haven't checked this code on the code you've linked to, so it might "break" other things. This answer is for you to understand the logic behind this so you could change it yourself.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation and invaluable when it comes to backtesting. Thank you for this.

Comment: I haven't able to implement the strategy.exit as you described for SLs on the chart I linked. I was able t implement it into another startegy but I'm getting mixed results. Do you ever take on commissions?